# Are Realtime Database transactions also given a null argument initially in Cloud Functions?

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, transactions, google-cloud-functions

It's been said many times that when using Realtime Database transactions, the transaction is most likely going to be called first with a `null` argument before it is called again with the actual value of the the target node being its argument. The reason or this is stated to be due to a delay in updating local caching.

So what about for Cloud Functions? I would think that since Cloud Functions are server-side, this doesn't happen. However, I'm still curious, since I suppose the true answer depends on how they implemented Cloud Functions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It does still happen.  It has nothing to do with Cloud Functions - it is just the way the Realtime Database client SDKs work.  The node SDK is in use in Cloud Function, just like any node client.